# Log4net log in developer machine, but in test server doesn't log

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, log4net

I'm using log4net 1.2.11. So, the logging is working in developer machine, but when i publish in a test server it is not working. Debugging remotely, i saw that the log is load correctly in ILog variable, but when it calls log.Error(), nothing happens, no log file, no log4net exception.

Any ideias?

Obs: i'm using the log4net in a asp.net mvc 3 website.

-- EDIT

I put Full Control to EVERYONE... nothing change, no log file.

Comment: ApplicationPoolIdentity is the default identity for IIS 7.5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enable log4net debugging to get more information about the problem. Without this, log4net fails silently and it's very hard to troubleshoot configuration issues.

Check [**How do I enable log4net internal debugging?**](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html) on log4net FAQS

Take into account if you have permissions problems (as [Shyju](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40521/shyju) pointed out) that the default identity for IIS 7.5 is `ApplicationPoolIdentity` and not `Network Service`

[Here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/) you have instructions about how to secure resources for ApplicationPoolIdentity
. Check section "Securing Resources"

Comment: The `ApplicationPoolIdentity` doesn't exist. =(

Comment: @Vinicius Otton: Added a link to help you to mamage permissions for ApplicationPoolIdentity

Comment: I find the user NetworkService that is a possible user to IIS Pool Identity. There is any problem or anything that i have to consider after change the IIS Pool Identity to NetworkService? Because the  ApplicationPoolIdentity doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you see the new link I've added a couple of days ago? (http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/) You'll find there how to secure ApplicationPoolIdentity in case you need it.

Comment: Quicklink on the FAQ http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#internalDebug

Answer (score 5):

Check the folder has sufficient permissions for ASP.NET to write a file to that. Most probably that is the reason **if it worked in Dev machine**

Some workarounds

in your Dev maching delete the log file and folder and run it as new and see whether it creates log file. If yes, there is nothing to change in code. It should be a permission thing. So Lets double check the permissions

As [Claudio Redi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/245860/claudio-redi) mentioned in his answer, You can also enable internal debugging of log4net to get more info. 
Check the section called "**How do I enable log4net internal debugging?**" for more details in this link http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html

From their documentation

> **Why can't I log to a FileAppender from a web application?**
>
> The web application runs as a special user account on the web server
>   called ASPNET. This account has restricted permissions to protect the
>   web server from attacks. By default this account may not have
>   permission to write to the file system. Make sure that the ASPNET
>   account has permission to create and write to files in the directory
>   chosen for logging.

Comment: I put Full Control to NETWORK SERVICE and nothing change... no log file.

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni : As part of testing the permission, give permission to "Everyone" and see whether it is bringing any changes. then you can take away that and give specific permission for ASP.NET user

Comment: I put Full Control to EVERYONE and nothing change, no log file. =(

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni : Did you tried what i said in my updated answer ? delete log folder in dev machine and try again

Comment: Yep. The log was created again in the dev machine.

Comment: what is your log file location in config file ? Is it hardcoded to a purticular disk or something ? try changing that to a simple file name only and see whether it creates the log file in root

Comment: "try changing that to a simple file name only" - It is already this, look: `<file value="log.txt" />`

Comment: "Why can't I log to a FileAppender from a web application?" - i put Full Control to everyone, and keeps without logging.

Comment: `log4net:ERROR [FileAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure. Unable to acquire lock on file C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sttenterprise\log.txt. Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sttenterprise\log.txt' is denied.` why? I put full control to everyone...

Comment: Don't you think that If you append my answer to yours would be fair to mention that you did it?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi : Sure. I will mention that

Comment: Now it worked. Oo - But with permissions to everyone. What is the asp.net user? Is the NETWORK SERVICE user in IIS7.5?

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni : Dont give "Everyone" permission. Its dangerous. We gave that for debugging only. Look for IUSer. I am not sure about IIS7.5

Comment: Full control to IUsr and Network Service, and nothing change. =(

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the reference to `log4.config` inside `web.config` was wrong:

```
<add key="log4net.Config" value="log4.config"/>
```

points to the root folder, and on my dev machine, `log4.config` was actually there, so logging would work.

However, on a build, `log4.config` is copied to the `bin` folder, the only place it would be after a deploy.

Changing the `web.config` to

```
<add key="log4net.Config" value="bin/log4.config"/>
```

made logging work everywhere for me

Comment: This is the solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I was searching for solution to this problem from last couple of day and this  worked for me too.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the log  folder has permission for Default AppPool[image]

If the permission is not there , add DefaultAppPool  to the group
[image]